# Convert NSString to double for calculations and then back again to print in NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uipickerview, nsnumber

I accept NSString as

```
NSString *value = [valuelist objectAtIndex:valuerow];
NSString *value2 = [valuelist2 objectAtIndex:valuerow2];
```

from UIPickerView.
I want to

```
double *cal = value + (value2 * 8) + 3;


NSString *message =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",cal];
```

I should be able to get the string in message after I do the calculations on it .. Please help
My program is crashing

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
double cal = [value doubleValue] + ([value2 doubleValue] * 8) + 3;
NSString *message =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",cal];
```

Comment: Now that is just completely subjective

Comment: I looked around and so far %f and %g seem to be identical according to most references. How are they different?

Comment: @tc. what's wrong with you? That's subjective, don't be arrogant. +1 for compensation.

Comment: `%g` will not give you 300 digits of output unless you ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't convert between doubles and strings all the time, since it tends to lose accuracy (in general, you have to be *very careful* if you don't want to lose accuracy).

For example, `nextafter(1.0,2.0)` returns the smallest double larger than 1 (exactly 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625, but we're happy with 1.0000000000000002). Formatting with "%g" just returns "1".

We'd expect NSNumber to do the right thing, but `[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:nextafter(1,2)] stringValue]` also returns "1". According to the docs, `-[NSNumber stringValue]` calls `[self descriptionWithLocale:nil]` which formats it with "%0.16g". That's not enough. We get the right answer by formatting with "%.17g", though. I think "%.17g" is enough provided that doubles are IEEE 754 64-bit doubles and the libraries are working properly, but there's no guarantee.

At the end of the day, there's no guarantee that `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.17g",n] doubleValue] == n`.

Comment: Thanks for that but i just needed upto 2 decimals places .. ie : 12.50

Answer (score 1):

```
double cal = [value doubleValue] + ([value2 doubleValue] * 8) + 3;
NSString *message =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",cal];

// do work with message

[message release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting a new answer since the accepted one only does string=>double:

```
double cal = [value doubleValue] + ([value2 doubleValue] * 8) + 3;
NSString *message =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",cal];
```

To go double=>string, use

```
double cost = [string doubleValue];
```

Comment: why the pointer? It should be double cost = [string doubleValue];

Comment: good point.  on a meta level... why the comment?  just edit the post? :D